# Problem setting Android tab background color

Tags: android, colors, background, tabwidget

I'm adding tab icon via selector like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_cart_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_cart" />
</selector>
```

http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/2535/questionn.jpg

All is fine, but my icon is smaller then tab itself and I want to set background color same as icon color. But I cant seem to figure out hot to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a .png transparency.

[How to Make a Transparent PNG](http://www.ehow.com/how_2029201_png-photoshop.html)

test with this [image](http://www.fp.utm.my/projek/psm/juzclick/images/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png) and you will see